# Run go app by service

Tags: command-line, centos, services

In centos 6.8 I have a golang app , that run in command `go run main.go` and I need to create a system service to run it in boot like service httpd.
I know that I have to create file like `/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd` But I don't know how to do it to run that command.

Answer (score 0):

If no script exists anywhere for your app then have a look on your system for the following file;

`sysvinitfiles` on my Centos 6.8 system its located at `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.03.53/` but if you do a `locate` you should find it.

It's a skeleton script that you can copy, modify then use for most things. Once you get it configured you can use it via `chkconfig` as you would any other init script.

There are a couple of good websites which may help [here](https://techarena51.com/index.php/how-to-create-an-init-script-on-centos-6/) and [here](https://blog.hazrulnizam.com/create-init-script-centos-6/).